# PHP photo stored in Blob cutting off

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

I have created a photo uploader, it works. I can upload photos and then display them. The problem I am having is that the images are sometimes not being loaded all the way. It seems like PNGs have no problem displaying but jpg seem to be getting cut off(like the whole image is not stored in the blob only the top portion. See below.

Form

```
   <?php echo Form::open('', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'photoUpload')); ?>

         <input name="files[]" id="files" type="file" multiple="" />
         <button type="submit" id="photo" name="photo" value="Submit " /> Submit Photos</button>
         </form>
```

Writing to database.

```
 if(isset($tmpName) && isset($mimeType) && isset($fileName)){
        // Read the file
        $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
       // $data = addslashes($data);
        fclose($fp);



        if($data){

            echo $fileName;
            echo $id;   
         $parameters = array(':id' => null,
                            ':idd' => $id,
                            ':filename' => $fileName,
                            ':mime' => $mimeType,
                            ':c_id' => null,
                            ':FOrder' => null,
                            ':pBlob' => $data,
                     );

         DB::insert('photos')
                ->values(array_keys($parameters))
                ->parameters($parameters)
                ->execute($this->db);
            }
        }
```

Photos being accessed

```
  for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   echo "<img src='data:".$photos[$i]->mime.";base64,"  
    . base64_encode($photos[$i]->photoBlob). "' style='width: 80px;' />";
                            }
```

Comment: it is generally recommended not to store the image as a blob in a db, but store it as a file, and just put the name\location in the db

Comment: also not all browsers support img src data

Comment: soo what you are saying is this approach is not the best..?

Comment: i second not storing as blob. for a long time I used blob, and it's fine if you have a small number of pictures, but unless it's very few pictures using the filesystem is much better.

Comment: So yeah, not best practice.  Back to your question though.  Have you looked to see if it is being truncated at a certain number of bytes?  Might be your PHP settings for textsize/textlimit (not sure on what database you are using...).

Comment: I am using mysql running on a wamp server. I understand there are some php.ini settings related to something similar. I bumped up a setting which allowed me to upload 100+ photos at a time. Donno if this is what you are refering to "
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 8M"

Comment: Take a look at strict mode (`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`), you might be truncating and not getting an error.  Otherwise suppose maybe the MySQL setting for `max_allowed_packet` could come into play if these are of a certain size.